# Integral calculus .

Tags: indefinite-integrals

This is a wonderful integral .already been able to find some steps to solve it but always incomplete .
The integral is stated below.
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\mbox{arcsinh}(x)}{1+x^2} dx$$
Need a nice soln , i have a wonderful feeling it will be complex.hint; why not transforming the inverse hyperbolic function to a logarithmic function that would have make our work easier , i also tried that but not efficent to finish my soln.
But trying it using differentiation under sign might also work during this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the integral in Maple gives

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\mbox{arcsinh}(x)}{1+x^2} dx=$$

[image]

Only posting this as a bit of information, not attempt at solution.

Comment: Very cool result...but the main issue now is evaluation.